# BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of

Tags: vb.net

i need help with my code

```
Public Class Forma
Private Sub ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProjectToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click() Then
        Print(Form_load)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form_load(FormB As Object)

End Sub


End Class
```

but i keep getting BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of. What am i doing wrong

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to check if the `ProjectToolStripMenuItem` was clicked or not. If that is the case, what you are doing is unnecessary. The `ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click` method will be called every time you click the menu item; there's no need to verify that it was clicked because you can be 99% certain _**that it was**_.

Comment: I suggest you go find yourself a programming book or tutorial to familiarize yourself with the VB.NET language. What you're currently doing both in your `If`-statement and the `Print(Form_Load)` call is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition want to check the result of the event `ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click` (click event of `ProjectToolStripMenuItem`). On this function you don't define the `sender` and `e` parameter.

You should review your code and fix the issues:

```
Public Class Forma
    Private Sub ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProjectToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If exampleFunction() Then '<-- choose the correct function or variable
            Print(Form_load) '<-- Form_load?? maybe FormB??
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form_load(FormB As Object)

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Some basics you should know:**

- A `Sub` doesn't return a value, so you can't use a `Sub` on a condition (only functions, variables and values can be used on a condition).
- It looks like you check if the button / menu item was clicked by the user. You don't need to check because the event `ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click` is called automatically if the user click on `ProjectToolStripMenuItem`. At the point you try to check the button / menu item was clicked it was actually clicked. You can find more information about `Event Handlers` on the [official .NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/event-handlers-overview-windows-forms).

---

The error message should be clear enough to solve the issue:

> You have not supplied an argument for a required parameter.
>
> **To correct this error:**
>
> - Supply an argument for the specified parameter.
>
> **source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30455

---

**You try to [print the form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/printing/how-to-print-a-form-by-using-the-printform-component) on button click?**

```
Public Class Forma
    Private printForm as Object

    Private Sub ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProjectToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If ConditionIsTrue() Then '<-- choose the correct Sub or Function
            Me.printForm.Print()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form_load(FormB As Object)
        '... maybe some other stuff

        Me.printForm = FormB

        '... maybe some other stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The most accurate answer so far. Though you should perhaps explicitly mention that `ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click` does not return anything, and therefore cannot be checked in an `If`-statement. -- I _think_ what the OP is trying to do is check if the menu item _**was actually clicked**_. While doing so is completely unnecessary, I've seen many new programmers trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a Sub as a Parameter `Print(Form_load)`.  `FormB.Print()` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem : `If ProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click() Then`

It's a call to the same sub and it has no parameters specified.